# multimodule maven gwt project - dependency resolution in hosted mode problem

Tags: gwt, maven, build

Recently I've split my GWT 2.4 application into two maven modules: **domain** and **webapp**. Domain module (according to its name) contains domain classes and webapp contains all other GWT-related stuff. **Webapp** depends on **domain**.

Everything is almost the same as described here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html

When I run (from reactor):

```
mvn clean package
```

maven builds application WAR appropriately: first it compiles **domain**, then **webapp**, next creates war file which can be deployed on tomcat and works fine.
However, if I try to run application in the hosted mode:

```
mvn gwt:run
```

maven tries to resolve dependency to **domain** module in my local repository and remote repositories. Since I've deleted it from my local repo, maven can not find it and build (hosted mode) fails. Of course I can install **domain** module into my local repo first, but it's smells like a dirty workaround for me. **Domain** has been removed from local maven repository intentionally in order to make sure that hosted mode runs with the old (outdated) version taken from local repo, instead of working with the previously built **domain** artifact.

If **domain** module was installed in my local repository, after `mvn clean package` completed, **webapp** target directory contains exploded WAR with the recent version of **domain** JAR. When I run `gwt:run`, new version of domain artifact (in target) is replaced with the outdated one taken from local repo (I can see changes)!

How is this possible? Is it a bug in gwt maven plugin? Is there any way to avoid such strange plugin behavior?

Comment: Isn't that simply how Maven works? Unless you use a _reactor_ module, you have to install your dependencies in your local repo.

Comment: @Thomas but if I create GWT WAR package, I'd expect that maven plugin in gwt:run use libraries (their newest versions) included within this package instead of obtaining them from repository (since 'mvn package' does not install them, repo versions might be outdated). I don't mean retrieving domain library from webapp WAR, but just to use the newly build domain package. It sounds reasonably for me, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd love it if I could tell Maven to run a goal on a submodule but use the dependencies from the "sibling" submodules rather than resolve them from the repos. I unfortunately haven't found how to do it, and I highly suspect it's simply not possible, and people do `mvn install`s all day long.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe it's exactly how you described. From one point of view it makes sense, but from the other it would be great to use the most recent dependencies instead of installed in repo. I think that it is all about how GWT plugin is implemented - especially that webapp does not need to be installed before gwt:run. If gwt:run must assemble war to deploy it on jetty, why it does not use war that has been previously assembled (by package goal) instead of assembling the new one (with outdated domain dependency from repo), or assemble it in the same way as "package"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might this be a solution for you?
http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/productivity.html
For me it works. I have different modules as well. With the help of the link I can make changes in the domain module and simply restart the hosted mode. Doesn't work for all changes though.